# How can I count the number of occurrences of a category in dataset as part of an Sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data, encoding

Let us say we have a dataset with a feature such as Surname:

```
arr['Surname'] = ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Johnson', 'Smith']
```

And I would like to encode this categorical info as a new feature like:

```
arr['Surname_Count'] = [2, 1, 1, 2]
```

with the caveat that it is done **within a scikit-learn pipeline**. Are there quick ways to do this that do not involve rolling my own partition counting transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be late but I found this question interesting:

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer, make_column_selector as selector
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, MinMaxScaler

iris = load_iris()
X, _ = iris.data, iris.target
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns= iris.feature_names)

valores = ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Johnson']

np.random.seed(42)
X["categoria"] = np.random.choice(a = valores, size = X.shape[0])
```

**Gives:**

[image]

**To validate results:**

```
X.categoria.value_counts()
```

[image]

```
def f(series):
    mapeo = series.value_counts().to_dict()
    series = series.replace(mapeo)
    return series


preprocessor = make_column_transformer((MinMaxScaler(), selector(dtype_exclude= "object")),
                        (FunctionTransformer(lambda x: f(x)), selector(dtype_include= "object"))).fit(X)

pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.transform(X))
```

**Returns:**

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Featuretools](https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools), which an open source python framework for automated feature engineering. Specifically for you, it can generate [aggregation features such as count](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/primitives.html#aggregation-vs-transform-primitive) for your dataset.

After generating the new feature matrix with the desired column, you can use the matrix as you normally would within a scikit-learn pipeline.